# Want to create a table using XSL/XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I’m trying to create a table using XSL/XML. I'm new to XSL and XML, so go easy on me please 
I’m having a bit of trouble with a few things.
This is my XML file:

```
<List>
<Classification>
    <Class>
        <Label>Milk</Label>
        <NumberZone>1</NumberZone>

        <Zone>
            <Label>Milk1</Label>
            <Frontier>500</Frontier>
        </Zone>

        <Zone>
            <Label>Milk2</Label>
            <Frontier>600</Frontier>
        </Zone>

        <Zone>
            <Label>Milk3</Label>
            <Frontier>600</Frontier>
        </Zone>

        <Zone>
            <Label>Milk4</Label>
            <Frontier>700</Frontier>
        </Zone>

        <image>
            <File>milk.jpg</File>
        </image>
    </Class>

    <Class>
        <Label>Water</Label>
        <NumberZone>2</NumberZone>

        <Zone>
            <Label>Water1</Label>
            <Frontier>800</Frontier>
        </Zone>

        <Zone>
            <Label>Water2</Label>
            <Frontier>900</Frontier>
        </Zone>

        <image>
            <File>water.jpg</File>
        </image>
    </Class>

    <Class>
        <Label>Juice</Label>
        <NumberZone>3</NumberZone>

        <Zone>
            <Label>Juice1</Label>
            <Frontier>950</Frontier>
        </Zone>

        <Zone>
            <Label>Juice2</Label>
            <Frontier>990</Frontier>
        </Zone>

        <image>
            <File>juice.jpg</File>
        </image>
    </Class>

</Classification>
</List>
```

It normally is longer, but I cut out some parts.

I want my table to look like this:

- First column: Milk, Water, Juice...
- Second column: I want the images.
- Third column: Milk1, Water1, Juice1.
- Fourth column: Milk2, Water2, Juice2.
- (And so on).

So far I have this:

```
<table border="1">

 <tr><th>Column 1</th><th>Image</th><th>Column 3</th></tr>


        <xsl:for-each select="Classification/Class">
        <tr>
            <td><em><xsl:value-of select="Label" /></em></td>

            <td>
            <xsl:attribute name="src">
            <xsl:value-of select="image/File"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            </td>

            <td><xsl:value-of select="Zone/Label"/></td>
            <td colspan="1"><xsl:value-of select="Zone/Label"/></td>
            <td colspan="1"><xsl:value-of select="Zone/Label"/></td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
</table>
```

- This displays the first column perfectly with Milk, Water, and Juice.
- The second column doesn't work, it's just blank. The image won't appear in the table, any idea on how to fix this?*
- The third column also works perfectly showing Milk1, Water1, Juice1.
- The fourth column doesn't work, obviously, because I'm using the same value-of as in the third column. I don't know how to get Milk2, Water2, and Juice2 to show in that column, since it uses the same element name (being Zone/Label)

**So there's two thing I need to fix: I need to fix the second column to actually show the image in each boxes.
I also need to fix the fourth column to show Milk2, Water2, and Juice2.
My main problem for now is to get the fourth column to work, I really don't understand how to display Milk2, Water2, etc.**

I would also like to add either radio buttons, or check boxes later on in each cell, so I could use JavaScript in my web page. I feel like each box would need a different ID, so I'm not sure how to achieve that using XSL, since it just does a "loop" through the XML file, so I'm not sure how I would add a radio button, or a check box in each cell. * This isn't as important for now, I'll work on that after I'd rather have help with what I mentioned before, but this would be helpful too.

EDIT:

I have two problems.
I managed to add check boxes by doing something like this:

```
<td colspan="1"><input type="checkbox" name="Zone1" id="Zone1" /><xsl:value-of select="Zone[1]/Label"/></td>
<td colspan="1"><input type="checkbox" name="Zone2" id="Zone1" /><xsl:value-of select="Zone[2]/Label"/></td>
<td colspan="1"><input type="checkbox" name="Zone3" id="Zone1"/> <xsl:value-of select="Zone[3]/Label"/></td>
<td colspan="1"><input type="checkbox" name="Zone4" id="Zone1" /><xsl:value-of select="Zone[4]/Label"/></td>
```

The problem is, I think every elements in each column will have the same ID, am I right? How do I change it so they all have a different ID?

Also, it can't be seen from the XML file in my question, but later on there would only be, for example, Milk4. meaning I would want the cells for Water4 and Juice4 to dissapear completely, but it's still there, empty with a check box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your second column, you are doing this

```
<td>
   <xsl:attribute name="src">
   <xsl:value-of select="image/File"/>
   </xsl:attribute>
</td>
```

But this results in the following HTML

```
<td src="milk.jpg" />
```

However, you really need to use the **img** tag to display the image, so do this instead.

```
<td>
   <img src="{image/File}" />
</td>
```

As for the third and fourth columns, you can add an xpath expression to specify the position.

```
<xsl:value-of select="Zone[1]/Label"/>
<xsl:value-of select="Zone[2]/Label"/>
```

In fact, to avoid some code repetition, it might be better to use template matching here

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="Zone[position() &lt; 3]" />

 <xsl:template match="Zone">
     <xsl:value-of select="Label"/>
 </xsl:template>
```

And if you wanted to extend this to show your check boxes, you could do something like this

```
<xsl:template match="Zone">
   <xsl:variable name="index">
      <xsl:number />
   </xsl:variable>
   <input type="checkbox" name="Zone{$index}" id="Zone{$index}" />
   <xsl:value-of select="Label"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Note how this makes use of "Attribute Value Templates" to output the id. The curly braces { } indicate it is an expression to be evaluated, rather than output literally.

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/List">
      <table border="1">
         <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Image</th>
            <th>Column 3</th>
         </tr>
         <xsl:for-each select="Classification/Class">
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <em>
                     <xsl:value-of select="Label"/>
                  </em>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <img src="{image/File}"/>
               </td>
               <td colspan="1"><xsl:apply-templates select="Zone[1]" /></td>
               <td colspan="1"><xsl:apply-templates select="Zone[2]" /></td>
               <td colspan="1"><xsl:apply-templates select="Zone[3]" /></td>
               <td colspan="1"><xsl:apply-templates select="Zone[4]" /></td>
            </tr>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Zone">
      <xsl:variable name="index">
         <xsl:number />
      </xsl:variable>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Zone{$index}" id="Zone{$index}" />
      <xsl:value-of select="Label"/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML, the following is output

```
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Image</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <em>Milk</em>
      </td>
      <td>
         <img src="milk.jpg"/>
      </td>
      <td colspan="1">
         <input type="checkbox" name="Zone1" id="Zone1"/>Milk1</td>
      <td colspan="1">
         <input type="checkbox" name="Zone2" id="Zone2"/>Milk2</td>
      <td colspan="1">
         <input type="checkbox" name="Zone3" id="Zone3"/>Milk3</td>
      <td colspan="1">
         <input type="checkbox" name="Zone4" id="Zone4"/>Milk4</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <em>Water</em>
      </td>
      <td>
         <img src="water.jpg"/>
      </td>
      <td colspan="1">
         <input type="checkbox" name="Zone1" id="Zone1"/>Water1</td>
      <td colspan="1">
         <input type="checkbox" name="Zone2" id="Zone2"/>Water2</td>
      <td colspan="1"/>
      <td colspan="1"/>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <em>Juice</em>
      </td>
      <td>
         <img src="juice.jpg"/>
      </td>
      <td colspan="1">
         <input type="checkbox" name="Zone1" id="Zone1"/>Juice1</td>
      <td colspan="1">
         <input type="checkbox" name="Zone2" id="Zone2"/>Juice2</td>
      <td colspan="1"/>
      <td colspan="1"/>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I will try to get the radio buttons working, if I can't get it to work I'll ask more questions.

Comment: I had a few problems and edited my question, if you could look at it.